# How to delete a specific data from ecxel - python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

How can I delete a specific data from all rows in an ecxel file using python?

Like the "-" data in rows

[image]

Comment: you want to delete the rows with - ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove them and leave them blank you could use a replace

```
df = df.replace('-', '')
```

If you are looking to remove the entire row/column that contain a '-' please specify that and the code can be updated.